# Can I use "critic" for an inanimate entity?

Tags: word-request

I'm writing a sentence and I cannot think of a good word to fit in.

> ...However, input hypothesis, despite its popularity and great contribution that it made, did not go without criticism. Noticing hypothesis and comprehensible output hypothesis were the main [*the word*] of it.

My first thought was to use *critic*, but it seems *critic* is used to describe a person. Can I use it here, too? If not, what word can I use there without being awkward?!

I should say that I can't use *rival* here either, I really hope I could, because these two theories propose that *input hypothesis* is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: The word *critic* doesn't really seem to make sense there whether you mean a person or an inanimate entity.  Frankly, your second sentence doesn't really make sense at all.  It looks like "Noticing hypothesis and comprehensible output hypothesis" is the subject of the sentence, so I'm not sure where *critic* fits in the sentence.  Do you mean that those were the main *criticisms* of it?

Comment: I'd like to say that these hypotheses put forward some neglected aspects of input hypotheses without rejecting it completely. Can I use _criticisms_ as you mentioned? As in "Noticing hypothesis and comprehensible output hypothesis were the main **criticisms** of it" since I think they pointed out some criticism rather being the criticism themselves.

Comment: I've no idea whether *input hypothesis, noticing hypothesis,* and *comprehensible output hypothesis* are recognised terms in some technical context, but none of it reads like normal English to me. And if they really *are* valid "jargon", I'd at least expect each reference to be preceded by the definite article.

Comment: @FumbleFingers let's replace the hypotheses with article 1, article 2, and article 3 (in newspapers), so the sentence would read: "However, **article 1**, despite its popularity and great contribution that it made, did not go without criticism. **article 2** and **article 3** were the main [the word] of it. Can I use _critics_ to describe the articles?

Comment: Now you're just confusing the issue even more. I can imagine that someone might come up with a hypothesis B that explicitly and inherently contradicted some *other* hypothesis A (because B involved the application of logic and principles in direct opposition to principles embodied by A). But it gets increasingly difficult to see how an ***article*** could criticise or otherwise detract from a hypothesis. I suggest you abandon the whole metaphor.

Comment: I'd have suggested *criticism*, too. I think instead of *critic* (a person profesionalising in giving criticism) you mean *critique* ([from french](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/critique)). If sounds wrong to you, because criticism would be used in two [different meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criticism), I'd suggest point of criticism or critical points or counter arguments etc. etc.

Comment: How about **arguments against** or, as Hector von says, **counter-arguments**?

Comment: @JavaLatte yea, i quite like it though i need to rephrase the sentence, _"they raised the main arguments against it."_ while we're at it can i say _"they made the main criticisms **to** it"_

Comment: @Yuri, we normally use the preposition **of** after **criticisms**. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=criticisms+about%2C+criticisms+of%2C+criticisms+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccriticisms%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccriticisms%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccriticisms%20to%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *critic* is a person who gives critiques or reviews.  If a critic says something negative, that "something negative" isn't called a critic.  You cannot use "critics" to describe the articles.

> Noticing hypothesis and comprehensible output hypothesis were the main [the word] of it.

*Criticism* can be used the way you want, as in "X is the main criticism of it", but will sound wierd since you already used that word in an earlier sentence.

A *shortcoming* is a concise word to describe a neglected aspect.  You can also use *flaw* or *deficiency.*

> > Noticing hypothesis and comprehensible output hypothesis were the main { shortcomings | flaws | deficiencies } of it.

Given "The latter hypotheses (Noticing H & Comprehesible Output H) are not part of the former (input H). They were proposed later by other researchers as a reaction to the shortcomings they found in the first hypothesis" in your comments ...

I don't think a single word can express this in English.

I don't really think you can do better than "improved hypothesis" here, if it is accepted as improved.  If it is not accepted as improved, I would consider a term such as "evolved hypothesis" or "further-developed hypothesis."

Comment: The latter hypotheses (Noticing H & Comprehesible Output H) are not part of the former (input H). They were proposed **later** by other researchers as a reaction to the shortcomings they found in the first hypothesis. I'm saying this because I think the last sentence of yours implies that the latter hypotheses are the flaws of the first hypothesis. In other words, I think you take that N.H and C.O.H are subject to criticism while it's not the case. It's the other way around. I.H is being criticised **by** N.H and C.O.H.

Comment: See edits to my answer.

Comment: Yea, thank you. I think i can use **further developed** as an adjective phrase and go with _indicating the shortcomings of it, further-develoed hypotheses x and y were the main improved versions of I.H_ does it sound good?

Comment: Sounds good to this non-scientific native speaker.

Comment: You've been of great help :) + 1